# Do "I ate many noodles today" and "you should eat many vegetables" sound wrong?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

According to dictionary "**[noodle](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/noodle?q=noodle)**" is a countable noun and often in plural form

I learned that we can use "**many**" before countable nouns.

Does "**I ate many noodles today**" sound wrong?

In addition, "[vegetable](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vegetable?q=vegetable)" is also a countable noun

Does "**you should eat many vegetables**" sound wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noun "noodle" is countable, and this expression is grammatical:

> I ate many noodles today.

However, it is unidiomatic. People don't count the number of noodles they are eating. (Unless they are fanatical dieters!)

The idiomatic expression is

> I ate a lot of noodles today.

The situation with "vegetables" is a little different, because "many vegetables" can mean a wide variety of different kinds of vegetables.

> You should eat many vegetables.

probably means that you should eat many different vegetables.

If you are saying that someone should increase the amount of vegetables in their diet, then you would say

> You should eat a lot of vegetables.

Comment: Similarly, _spaghetti_ is plural in Italian but English speakers treat it as uncountable, as though it were a substance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is odd in meaning, it suggests a focus on the number of strands of pasta.

These "plural uncountables" present some difficulties, as neither "much" nor "many" fit well.  Instead you can use "a lot of"

> I ate a lot of noodles.

Another option, that works well with vegetables, is "plenty"

> You should eat plenty of vegetables.

Again, it is not the number, but the amount and variety that is more important.  Eating 10 peas is not "plenty", eating 10 jackfruits is probably impossible.